# Spring SAML and internal post

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I am implementing a **SAML** authentication in a **Spring** project, with the spring-security-saml plugin and I achieved SSO without problems. Now I need to migrate a function in which we do a ***POST*** to another servlet in my app, where we previously managed the security with HTTP basic. We used org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient library, in this way:

```
HttpState hs = new HttpState();
AuthScope autScope = new AuthScope("host", "port");
hs.setCredentials(autScope, credentials);
```

Now, since we do not have the password, I was wondering which approach should be used to fix that. I am getting a 302 response since it tries -logically- to redirect to my SSO page. 
I read extensively the documentation of SAML but is difficult to me to understand where is the key. Maybe some work with SAML Assertion? Please give me some directions so I could read in a more precise way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that both the calling code and the POST endpoint are part of the same application? If so, I'm not sure why are you using an HTTP call instead of passing the call internally within the application.

In any case, one way to make it work is by sending JSESSIONID cookie of the authenticated user together with the POST call.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The reason of that design is because we have our application distributed in two servers for performance. It is a big application and the design wasn't my choice, but that's the architecture.